# Is it better to ask questions about Facebook Connect on stackoverflow, or the Facebook developer forum?

Tags: facebook

The FB developer forum seems to be the right place to ask questions about FB Connect, but I almost never get any kind of response, much less a good one. Do people get more help with FB Connect here on stackoverflow?

Comment: We know more about everything.  Facebook what now? ;)

Comment: Feel free to ask the question here, I'm sure some SO users have Facebook Connect experience and would be happy to help you out. As Seth pointed out in his answer, though, this question isn't really appropriate for SO.

Comment: If you *have* a question, go ahead ask it. But don't ask about asking questions, nor ask about StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

If you're having trouble getting a response, *both* is probably best. Self-answering whichever doesn't get the answer. Get the knowledge out there!

Comment: Don't most forums have a policy against duplicate posting?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the number of questions tagged [facebook-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-connect) (61 at this count). That's a big enough number to justify posting a question. However, this current question may be more appropriate for [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I did not know about meta, but I kinda' thought someone would mention something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not only FB Connect, but for the entire FB application development could be nice to discuss here too. I am also doing some project on FB application and receive only minimal helps and guidelines to get start with on FB forum, especially I am looking at solution on ASP.net MVC rather than their "official" PHP.